# How to keep alive client session in socket io connection for long time

Tags: javascript, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am using Flask-socketio python as a server and Javascript Socket-io as a client.

During emit event from server side client gets disconnected and reconnects again.

Due to this disconnection emit is not happening correctly.

How to keep the session alive or to avoid the disconnection?

And one more info I have tried testing it on win 7 pc, and there was no issue. On win 10 pc however the issue appears every time.
Is that related to an OS?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. To assist the community in helping you, please edit the question to include your relevant source code. I would also have a think about your application design here - being totally dependent, for an extended period, on an open socket connection sounds like a bad idea to me, even if they are sitting on the same OS instance.

Comment: In addition to the request above for source code, it would be useful to see logs from the server that show the disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your emit event takes some time after the event handler is called (probably processing some data etc.). 
If that is the case, increasing the ping_interval parameter on socketio instantiation will solve this issue. 
Server is expecting the client to send a ping every "ping_interval" (default=25 seconds) and assuming your frontend app is not sending these pings, flask socketio server assumes the client has left after 25 sec and disconnects the client. But processing time inside the event handler is more than 25 sec and when the it is time to emit the data you see disconnect message since there is not client to be emitted to.

You need to change this value to a higher value to make it work.

`socketio = SocketIO(app, ping_interval=50)`